# Website File Download Page

Tags: download-manager, server

I would like a web program (Ubuntu) that I could install on my server that would display a file to be downloaded.

The webpage would display the file name, size and date added, who added it, and have a button to start the download.

I was imagining something like the Dropbox link download page.

[image: dropbox download]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these:

1. H5ai ([larsjung.de/h5ai/](https://larsjung.de/h5ai/))
2. Literally just search [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20file%20manager&oq=php%20file%20manager)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about fixed content you can simply have a static link to the file, with whatever text and pictorial information that you desire.

For a more dynamic system just start an FTP server - this will give a view with the filename, size, date, etc., with some control over what information is displayed.

For still more control you can use a framework such as [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/), [django](https://django-ftpserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), etc., there are many possibilities.